# Knockout-validation in nested data structure

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a viewmodel for a form that I'm trying to add validation to using knockout-validation.

```
<table data-bind='visible: slots().length > 0'>
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: slots'>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="input-medium time-picker" data-bind='value: start_time' required="true"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="input-medium time-picker" data-bind='value: end_time' required="true"/></td>
            <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeSlot'><i class="icon-minus-sign"/></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind='click: addSlot'>Add Row</button>
```

I need to validate that if i enter "end_time" in row 1 and when i add new row than   start_time of row 2 must be greater than end_time of row 1.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use option deep, also if you want to have a validation group that wont work when adding new items to a array. You can work around it by wrapping the validation group in a observable and use a computed to enable disable your save button.

http://jsfiddle.net/vGTCz/2/

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.error = ko.observable();
    this.items = ko.observableArray();
    this.items.subscribe(this.onAdded, this); 

    this.canSave = ko.computed(this.getCanSave, this);
};

ViewModel.prototype = {
    onAdded: function() {
        this.error(ko.validation.group(this));
    },
    add: function() {
        this.items.push(new ItemViewModel());
    },
    getCanSave: function() {
        return this.error() && this.error()().length === 0;
    }
}
```